# Where to find POI data for places of worship (e.g. churches)?

Tags: data, united-states, point-of-interest

I am looking for free U.S. state-wide and/or county-wide shapefiles that include geographic locations for places of worship.  Examples include churches, temples, synagogues, and mosques.  In other words, I am looking for POI (points of interest) data, nothing more.  The attribute table fields would include something like FID, Shape, and Name of Place of Worship.  I am specifically looking for data in the U.S. state of Pennsylvania, but I eventually would also like the same location information for other states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datasets like these are usually maintained (if they exist) at the county level. You'll have to search your places of interest and see if county GIS departments have anything worth while.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for: 
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=007ff07891e34e339a6da82a5c44fd31
This provides the locations for hundreds of thousands of hospitals, educational institutions, places of worship, government offices, cemeteries, museums, and libraries. Each institution is named and shows the state and county it resides. You could also try GNIS data. Often a combination of sources is needed.